# Multiple checkboxes opening toggle divs each one. Only one can be selected at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, toggle

I have multiple checkboxes customized by CSS. With the function only one can be selected at the same time, like radios. I use toggle in onchange event to affect all changes in checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="plus" onchange="toggleByClass('masinfo1');" class="plusultra" id="checkmas1" value=""><label for="checkmas1"><span></span></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="plus" onchange="toggleByClass('masinfo2');" class="plusultra" id="checkmas2" value=""><label for="checkmas2"><span></span></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="plus" onchange="toggleByClass('masinfo3');" class="plusultra" id="checkmas3" value=""><label for="checkmas3"><span></span></label>
```

The divs:

```
<div class="masinfo1 divmasinfo" id="masinfo1"><p class="infop">1111 11111 111111 11111 1111 1111</p></div>
<div class="masinfo2 divmasinfo" id="masinfo2"><p class="infop">222222 222 222 22222222222</p></div>
<div class="masinfo3 divmasinfo" id="masinfo3"><p class="infop">33333 3333 333 3333 33</p></div>
```

The function toggle:

```
function toggleByClass(className) {
 $("."+className).toggle();}
```

The function only one checked:

```
    `$`( document ).ready(function() {
 `$`(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
      var $box = $(this);
      if ($box.is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
           $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $box.prop("checked", true);
      } else {
        $box.prop("checked", false);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

The problem is onchange don't close the div when I click another checkbox, and I don't understand why. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why not use radio buttons if the desired behaviour is the same?

Comment: Create a working jsfiddle so we can look at the problem working =]

Comment: I'm not sure your code is sync with your problem. If you have three checkboxes that open three different divs then you can have a common class on the divs and always close all of them if you click on checkbox and  just open the one related to that checkbox, maybe they can be related by a custom id.

Comment: I doubt this question will get a satisfactory answer without a working example.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c4ud3gm/) with the code so far. Add the rest of your code so you can get a proper answer

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657959/checkbox-menu-toggle) what you are wanting to do? Also, just FYI, when you create a fiddle, it would be a good idea to edit your question and add it there as well.

Comment: The problem still there, I add tree divs with the properly class, but in the jfiddle didnt runs.

Comment: btw, where's your `toggleByClass` function? can you please add it into the Question? And I think this is the function which you are using for hiding and showing those divs.

Comment: Think I posted all the code required, THX

Comment: I also tried with radiobuttons but I want to check and unchek them.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9c4ud3gm/3/

Answer (score 0):

You should hide the displayed divs before toggling. Please try with this toggleByClass function. It hides the already displayed divs before toggling.

```
function toggleByClass(className) {
    $(".divmasinfo").each(function(index, item) {
        if(!$(item).is("." + className)) {
            $(item).hide();
        }
    });
    $("." + className).toggle();
}
```